# What are the weather differences between different map themes?

Tags: cities-skylines

I've been playing the switch edition of Cities: Skylines, and I've noticed that when I play on a European map it rains a lot more than if I play on a tropical map. I tried to figure out if these differences applied to the other themes as well, but I don't have much time to experiment and the wiki has nothing about it. Has anybody calculated the weather frequencies for different themes in Cities: Skylines?

Comment: Please answer this.